# How to create server side stopwatch in java

Tags: java

I here attached my code .I used JavaScript for stopwatch but i need server side code can any one tell how to do and implement in project to start stopwatch in server side once the page is refreshed the timer is also in running state but i didn't get timer in running state after refreshed the page it shows zero.

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
        pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>  
    <%@page language="java"%>
    <%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
    <%@ page import="java.util.TimeZone"%>
    <%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
    <%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
    <%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
    <%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
    <%@ include file="Navbar.jsp"%>
          <%@ include file="defaultscreen.jsp" %>  
    <%@ include file="usernav.jsp"%>

    <%--  <%@ include file="examples/twenty-four-hour-clock.jsp"%>
     --%> <%@ page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat"%>
    <%@ page import="java.util.Date"%>
    <%@page import="java.text.ParseException"%>
    <%@ page import=" java.text.DateFormat"%>
    <%@ page import=" java.util.*"%>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">


    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>User Assignment</title>


      <script>
     function displayTime() {


            var today = new Date();
            var dd = today.getDate();
            var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
         var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

            if(dd<10){
                dd='0'+dd;
            } 
            if(mm<10){
                mm='0'+mm;
            } 
        var  date = yyyy+'/'+mm+'/'+dd;



             var hours = today.getHours() < 10 ? "0" + today.getHours() : today.getHours();
             var minutes = today.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + today.getMinutes() : today.getMinutes();
             var seconds = today.getSeconds() < 10 ? "0" + today.getSeconds() : today.getSeconds();

                time1 = date + " "+ hours + ":" + minutes; 

            time = date + " "+ hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds; 

            if (document.getElementById) {

                document.getElementById('Todaytimer').innerHTML = time;
                document.getElementById('start_time').value = time1;
                document.getElementById('pause_time').value = time1;
            } else if (document.layers) {
                document.layers.timer.document.write(time);
                document.layers.timer.document.close();
            }
            setTimeout("displayTime()", 1000);

        }
        window.onload = displayTime;
    </script>  

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flipclock.css">



    </head>
    <style>
    #user {
        font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
        height: 10%;            


    }

    #user1 {
        font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 21%;
    }

    #user td,#user th {
        border: 2px solid transparent;
        padding: 4px;
                top:220px;

    }

    #user tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #ffc680;
    }

    #user th {
        padding-top: -10px;
        padding-bottom: -10px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #00b0b3;
        color: black;
                top:220px;

    }


    .stopwatch .controls {
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    /* I'd rather stick to CSS rather than JS  for styling */

    .stopwatch .controls button{
        padding: 5px 15px;
        background :white;
        border: 3px solid  #FFF0;
        border-radius: 5px
    }

    .stopwatch .time {
        font-size: 185%;
    }
    .clock{
    float:right;
    right:-1045px; 
    top:-77px;
    position:relative; 
    font-size:10pt;
    }
    .start:hover{ 
       opacity: 0.3;
       filter: alpha(opacity=40);
       text-shadow: -2.4px -2.2px 0.933px green;


    }
    .start {
        opacity:2;
        filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }
    .pause:hover{ 
       opacity: 0.3;
       filter: alpha(opacity=40);
       text-shadow: -2.4px -2.2px 0.933px green;


    }
    .pause {
        opacity: 2.0;
        filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }
    .resume:hover{ 
       opacity: 0.3;
       filter: alpha(opacity=40);
       text-shadow: -2.4px -2.2px 0.933px green;


    }
    .resume {
        opacity: 2.0;
        filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }
    .stop:hover{ 
       opacity: 0.3;
       filter: alpha(opacity=40);
       text-shadow: -2.4px -2.2px 0.933px green;


    }
    .stop {
        opacity: 2.0;
        filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }
    #task {
        opacity: 0.2;
        filter: alpha(opacity=70); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }
    #task:hover {
        opacity: 2.0;
        filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }

    .well {
        min-height: 30px;
        padding: 19px;
        margin-bottom: 25px;
        background-image: url("./img/l23.jpeg");
        border: 5px solid #4f6d95cc;
        border-radius: 7px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(10, 10, 10, 1.05);
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(10, 10, 10, .05);
    }
    .form-control::-moz-placeholder {
        color: #141212;
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .form-control {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 34px;
        padding: 6px 12px;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 1.42857143;
        color: #0f0e0e;
        background-color: #fff;
        background-image: none;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 4px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
        -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
        -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
        transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    }
    </style>
    <body>


    <div class="clock"  ></div>






     <input id="start_time" type="hidden" name="start_time"  value="">
     <input id="pause_time" type="hidden" name="endtime" value="" > 
     <span id="Todaytimer"  style="float:right; display:none; left:-25px; top:-20px;position:relative; font-size:50pt; color: black;  "></span></body>


     <%
            String username = "";
     String id="";
     String mail="";
            String id2 = "";
            String email = "";

            HttpSession session1 = request.getSession(false);
            if(request.getSession().getAttribute("username")== null && request.getSession().getAttribute("id")== null  ) { 

                 response.sendRedirect("Home.jsp");
           }  
            else if(session1!=null){ 
            id2 = (String) session.getAttribute("id");
            System.out.print(id2);
            username = (String) session.getAttribute("username");
            email = (String) session.getAttribute("email");
            HttpSession session3 = request.getSession();

            /*  session3.setAttribute("email", email); */
                session3.setAttribute("email", email);
                session3.setAttribute("username", username);
            /* out.print(id2);
            out.print(username);
            out.print(email); */
            }
        %>

        <%
            String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.16.64:3306/timesheet";
            String userId = "allusers";
            String password = "whdb@123";

            try {
                Class.forName(driverName);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Connection connection = null;
            Statement statement = null;
            ResultSet resultSet = null;

            try
                {
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                }
                catch(Exception exe){}
                int id1 = 0;
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                            "jdbc:mysql://192.168.16.64:3306/timesheet", "allusers",
                            "whdb@123");

        Statement stmt = con.createStatement(
                ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
                    ResultSet rs = stmt
                            .executeQuery("SELECT tr.*,us1.username,pro.customer, pro.projectname, tsk.name,buttonstatus1 FROM ts_transaction tr JOIN ts_user us1 JOIN ts_project pro ON pro.id=tr.project_id    JOIN ts_task tsk ON tsk.id=tr.task_id  where tr.user_id=us1.id and us1.id='"+id2+"'  ");
                    rs.last();
                    int count = rs.getRow();
                    rs.beforeFirst();
        %>

        <div class="container" style="margin-top: 40px">
            <br>
            <br>
            <h2 align="center">
                <font style="color:white;"><strong><u>User Assignment</u></strong></font>
            </h2>
        </div>
    <%
            if (count > 0) {
        %>

        <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="well">
        <table id="user" align="center" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10"
            border="3">

            <tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#DEB887">
    <!--            <th align="center"><b>S.NO</b></th>
     -->            <th align="center"><b>User Name</b></th>
                <th align="center"><b>Customer Name</b></th>
                <th align="center"><b>Project Name</b></th>
                <th align="center"><b>Task Name</b></th>
                <th align="center"><b>Actual Start-Time</b></th>
                <th align="center"><b>Actual EndTime</b></th>
                <th align="center"><b>Total Duration</b></th>
                <th align="center"><b>User Operations</b></th>

                <th align="center"><b>Task Status</b></th>
            </tr>

            <%

                while (rs.next()) 
                {
                     id = rs.getString("id");
                    id1 = Integer.parseInt(id);

                    String user_id = rs.getString("username");
                    String customer_id = rs.getString("customer");
                    String project_id = rs.getString("projectname");
                    String task_id = rs.getString("name");
                    String start_time = rs.getString("start_time");
                    String end_time = rs.getString("end_time");

                    long difference = 0;
                    long diffMinutes = 0;
                    long diffHours = 0;
                    Date date1 = null;
                    Date date2 = null;
                    String date4 = "";
                    try 
                    {

                        String[] starttime = start_time.split(" ");
                        String s6 = starttime[1];//starttime

                        String[] endtime = end_time.split(" ");
                        String s7 = endtime[1];//endtime

                        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
                        format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
                        date1 = format.parse(s6);
                        date2 = format.parse(s7);
                        String stime1 = format.format(date1);
                        String stime2 = format.format(date2);
                        Date date5 = format.parse(stime1);

                        Date date6 = format.parse(stime2);
                        //String date4=format.format(date2);
                        difference = date6.getTime() - date5.getTime();
                        date4 = format.format(new Date(difference));

                    } 
                    catch (ParseException e) 
                    {
                        System.out.println(e);
                    } 
                    finally 
                    {

                    }

                    String status = rs.getString("status");
                    int i = Integer.parseInt(status);

                    Integer buttonstatus = rs.getInt("buttonstatus1"); 
                    //   b = Integer.parseInt(buttonstatus); 
                     System.out.println(buttonstatus+"button value from database"); 

            %>
            <tr>
    <%--            <td align="center" width="1%"><b><font color='green'><strong><%=n%></strong></font></b></td>
     --%>           <td align="center" width="1%"><b><font color='black'><strong><%=user_id%></strong></font></b></td>
                <td align="center" width="2%"><b><font color='black'><strong><%=customer_id%></strong></font></b></td>
                <td align="center"><b><font color='black'><strong><%=project_id%></strong></font></b></td>
                <td align="center"><b><font color='black'><strong><%=task_id%></strong></font></b></td>

                <td align="center" width="12%"><b><font color='black'><strong><%=start_time%></strong></font></b></td>
                <td align="center" width="12%"><b><font color='black'><strong><%=end_time%></strong></font></b></td>
                <td align="center" width="14%"><b><font color='black'><strong><%=date4%></strong></font></b></td>
                <%if(buttonstatus==4){%><td bgcolor="" align="center" width="35%" ><b>
                <font color='red'>
                   <strong>TASK FINISHED</strong></font></b>
                <%} else{%>
                <td align="center" width="35%"><b>
                <div class="stopwatch" >
        <div class="time">
            <span class="hours"></span> :
            <span class="minutes"></span> : 
            <span class="seconds"></span> 

        </div>
        <div class="controls">
        <%
    } 
    %>
        <input type="hidden" id="trans_id" value = "<%=id1%>" > 


        <% if( (buttonstatus==1) || (buttonstatus==2) || (buttonstatus==3) || (buttonstatus==4) )
    {
    %>
    <%--              <font color="white"><button  disabled  value = "<%=id1%>" style="border-radius:5px; background:#59878a66; border:560px;"  >Start  </button></font>
     --%>
        <% 
    } 
    else
    { 
    %>
                <font color="white"><button id="start<%=id1%>" class="start"   value = "<%=id1%>" style="border-radius:5px;  background:#0acb6b; border:560px;" title="Start Your Task!"  >START</button></font>

    <%
    } 
    %>
    <% if( (buttonstatus==0) || (buttonstatus==null) || (buttonstatus==2) || (buttonstatus==4) )
    {
    %>            
    <%-- <font color="white"><button id="pause<%=id1%>" disabled  style="border-radius:5px;  background:#59878a66; border:560px;"     >Pause</button></font>
     --%>
    <% 
    } 
    else
    { 
    %>            <font color="white"><button id="pause<%=id1%>"   class="pause"  value = "<%=id1%>" style="border-radius:5px;  background:red; border:560px;"     title="Hold Your Task">PAUSE</button></font> 

    <%
    } 
    %>
    <% if(   (buttonstatus==0)  || (buttonstatus==null) || (buttonstatus==1) || (buttonstatus==3) || (buttonstatus==4) )
    {%>       
    <%--  <font color="white"><button id="resume<%=id1%>" disabled style="border-radius:5px;  background:#59878a66; border:560px;">Resume</button></font>
     --%>
    <% 
    } 
    else
    { 
    %>        <font color="white"><button id="resume<%=id1%>" class="resume"    value = "<%=id1%>"  style="border-radius:5px;  background:#1fad9a; border:560px;"    title="Continue.."  >RESUME</button></font>

    <% 
    } 
    %>
    <% if( (buttonstatus==0) || (buttonstatus==null) || (buttonstatus==2) || (buttonstatus==4) ) 
    {%>

    <%-- <font color="white"> <button  disabled id="stop2<%=id1%>" style="border-radius:5px;  background:#59878a66; border:560px;"  >Stop</button></font>
     --%>
    <% 
    } 
    else
    { 
    %>       <font color="white"> <button class="stop" id="stop2<%=id1%>"    value = "<%=id1%>"  style="border-radius:5px; background:red; border:560px;" title="Finish"> STOP</button></font>

    <% 
    } 
    %>

        </div>

        </b></td>
                <% if(buttonstatus==0)
    {%>
                    <td bgcolor="#edff93" align="center" width="16%"><b><font color='BLACK'>
                    <strong>YET TO START..</strong></font></b></td>
    <%}%>
    <% if(buttonstatus==1)
    {%>
                    <td bgcolor="#0ae91c" align="center" width="16%"><b><font color='WHITE'>
                    <strong>TASK IN PROGRESS</strong></font></b></td>
    <%}%>

    <%if(buttonstatus==2){%>

                   <td bgcolor="#ff8787" align="center" width="16%"><b><font color='WHITE'>
                   <strong>TASK HOLDED!</strong></font></b></td>
    <%}%>
    <% if(buttonstatus==3)
    {%>
                    <td bgcolor="#89ff95" align="center" width="16%"><b><font color='BLACK'>
                    <strong>TASK CONTINUED...</strong></font></b></td>
    <%}%>
    <% if(buttonstatus==4)
    {%>
                    <td bgcolor="" align="center" width="16%" id="task">
                    </td>
    <%}%>
        </tr>

    <%if( (buttonstatus==1) || (buttonstatus==3))
    {

        id1 = Integer.parseInt(id);

        Statement stmt1 = con.createStatement();
        String sqlll="select * from ts_transaction tr where buttonstatus1 = '"+buttonstatus+"' and tr.id = '"+id1+"'  ";
        System.out.println(sqlll);

        ResultSet rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery(sqlll);

    }
    /*sql = "SELECT  tr.*,usr.username, pro.customer ,pro.projectname,tsk.name,tr.start_time,tr.end_time FROM ts_transaction tr 
    JOIN ts_project pro ON pro.id=tr.project_id 
    JOIN ts_task tsk ON tsk.id=tr.task_id 
    JOIN ts_user usr ON usr.id=tr.user_id WHERE   tr.id!=0   
    "+dbfrom+" "+dbto+"  "+dbusername+"  "+dbcustomer+"  "+dbprojectname+"  "+dbname+" ";
     */
    %>  
    <%}}%>  <%-- while loop end --%>


     </table>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>

    <script
            src="js/jquery.js"></script>

        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  

      <script>  

    $(function () {

    $('.stopwatch').each(function () {


            var element = $(this);

            var hoursElement = element.find('.hours');
            var minutesElement = element.find('.minutes');
            var secondsElement = element.find('.seconds');


            var hours, minutes, seconds, timer;

            function prependZero(time, length) 
            {
                time = '' + (time | 0);
                ///alert(time);
                while (time.length < length) time = '0' + time;
                return time;
            }
            function setStopwatch(hours, minutes, seconds) 
            {
                hoursElement.text(prependZero(hours, 2));
                minutesElement.text(prependZero(minutes, 2));
                secondsElement.text(prependZero(seconds, 2));

            }

            running = false;

            hours = minutes = seconds = milliseconds = 0;
            setStopwatch(hours, minutes, seconds); 

             function runTimer() 
            {

                 var start_Time  =  Date.now();
                 var prevHours   = hours;
                 var prevMinutes = minutes;
                 var prevSeconds = seconds;

                 timer = setInterval(function () 
                   {

                    var timeElapsed = Date.now() - start_Time;
                    hours   = (timeElapsed / 3600000) +prevHours;
                    minutes = ( (timeElapsed / 60000) + prevMinutes) % 60;
                    seconds = ( (timeElapsed / 1000) + prevSeconds) % 60;

                    setStopwatch(hours, minutes, seconds);
                 }, 25);
            } 

     element.find('.start').on('click', function () ///Start Function 
                    {


                var c=this.value;       

                 var  trans_id =  c;
                   var start_time = $('#start_time').val();

                var buttonstatus = 1;




                $.ajax({


                type : "POST",
                 url: "userassigncheckdb.jsp?current_starttime=" 
                         +start_time + 
                         "&&trans_id=" 
                         +trans_id+
                         "&&buttonstatus="
                         +buttonstatus,


                success : function(data) 
                {
                //location.reload();

                window.location = "timesheet.jsp";
                                         }
                          });  

                 running = true;
              runTimer();
              hours = minutes = seconds = milliseconds = 0;
              setStopwatch(hours, minutes, seconds); 

                    });

     element.find('.pause').on('click', function () ///Pause function
                    {

                var c=this.value;


                     var pause_time = $('#pause_time').val();
                      var trans_id =c;
                    var buttonstatus = 2;



                    $.ajax({


                    type : "POST",
                     url: "userassigncheckdb.jsp?current_stoptime=" +pause_time + "&&trans_id=" +trans_id+"&&buttonstatus="+buttonstatus,




                    success : function(data) 
                    {
                        location.reload();

                         window.location = "timesheet.jsp";



                                         }


                });  

                    running = false;
                    clearTimeout(timer);



            });
     element.find('.resume').on('click', function () ///Resume Function
                    {

            var c=this.value;




                    var  trans_id =  c;``
                   var start_time = $('#start_time').val();

                    var buttonstatus = 3;



                $.ajax({


                type : "POST",
                 url: "userassigncheckdb.jsp?current_starttime1=" +start_time + "&&trans_id=" +trans_id+"&&buttonstatus="+buttonstatus,


                success : function(data) 
                {
                    location.reload();

                     window.location = "timesheet.jsp";

                                     }


                        });  

                running = true;
                 runTimer();
                 hours = minutes = seconds = milliseconds = 0;
                 setStopwatch(hours, minutes, seconds);

            }); 
     element.find('.stop').on('click', function () //stopfunction
                    {
            var c=this.value;
                var trans_id =c;
                var pause_time = $('#pause_time').val();
                var buttonstatus = 4;

                $.ajax({

                 type : "POST",
                 url: "userassigncheckdb.jsp?current_stoptime2=" + pause_time + "&&trans_id=" +trans_id+"&&buttonstatus="+buttonstatus+" &&id2="+<%=id2%>,
                         success : function(data) 
                         {
                            location.reload();
                         window.location = "timesheet.jsp";

                         }
                 });                
                running = false;
                clearTimeout(timer);

            }); 

        });

    });
    </script>
    <script src="js/jquery4.min.js"></script>

            <script src="js/flipclock.js"></script>     
    <script type="text/javascript">
                var clock;

                $(document).ready(function() {
                    clock = $('.clock').FlipClock({
                        clockFace: 'TwentyFourHourClock'
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

Comment: Provide your code. Clarify what you really want to achiev and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51017371/edit) your question. Imagine what would your answer to this question be? It's way to broad.

Comment: I'm creating Time sheet Java web application here i need  server side stopwatch for a particular task to start but now i am  using Java script timer so intend of script i want to use server side stopwatch can you help me please

Comment: Please can you clarify a little more, what are you expecting the "stopwatch" to do?

Comment: Actually when team lead assign a task to his team member for a particular task he want to start that task with stopwatch timer whenever he needs break at that time he can able to pause the current task via stopwatch timer

Comment: Don't explain your question in the comments section, edit the question instead,

Answer (score -2):

I use this Library to create stop watch functionality in the server side.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/index.html?org/apache/commons/lang3/time/StopWatch.html

> import org.apache.commons.lang.time.StopWatch;

```
StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
stopWatch.start();
myCustomFunction()
stopWatch.stop();

System.out.println("Time Taken = "+ stopWatch.getTime()+ "MilliSeconds");
```

Here is the jsp answer you requested

```
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.lang.time.StopWatch" %>

<html>
<head>
<title>Basic StopWatch</title>
</head>
<body>

<%
    StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();

    stopWatch.start();
    out.println("Stop Watch Started, sleeping for 2000ms ");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    stopWatch.stop();

    out.println("<br/>Time Taken = "+ stopWatch.getTime()+ " MilliSeconds");

    out.println("<h1>Hello World!</h1>");
%>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you help me how to implement this stopwatch function in web application using Jsp do you have a code

Comment: @Rathan Naik  I will tell my brief introduction about my project.I am working on in Time sheet project in this project i am going to create a task to assign particular person having task name task assign time and task end time also then user goes to his login at that time assigned task will display in his sceen with opertation button of start,stop,resume etc while he click the start button the stopwatch timer should start at that time the server time should save in database while he clicking pause button again the server time will save in database

Comment: @Livinghome, what you've failed to comprehend is that if you don't improve the quality of your question it will be closed. So stop writing further explanations in the comments and stop treating SO as a code writing service.

Comment: @Livinghome I agree  with what Joakim Danielson has mentioned. I have given you the snippet for the core part, we cannot give you the entire project.